# Meteor Memory Creep

Tags: memory, meteor, out-of-memory, pm2

I created a Meteor application, deployed it using (`meteor build .`, `tar` and `node main.js`), on the live server using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). I continuously press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Chrome (Incognito) and see the memory usage on the server rocket up as it is creating a new connection for each client.

I returned the next morning and memory usage has gone from 169.949 MB to 188.129MB. Then, in an attempt to overload the system, I, again, continuously pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. The memory usage sharply dropped back down to around 175MB, and floats around that number.

This suggests that memory allocated for the connections are not shut down until someone access the page. Until then, memory will creep up.

**Is this assumption correct? If true, Why does memory keeps creeping up even when no one is visiting it? (site is authenticated using username/password) Why does it only go down when some connects, and not 'automatically'? Will this cause an OOM error eventually?**

Comment: I think you are observing just a regular behavior of node.js garbage collector. It is hard to make any conclusions without actually profiling your app.

Comment: @imslavko I assume that the leak (which is not really one) stops at some point in regular conditions?